# How do set default values in django for an HttpRequest.POST?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

how can i set a default value If the field is not sent?!
for example my code:

```
class SampleViewSet(ParentListAPIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        _email = self.request.data['email']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.request.data` is a `dict`, you can use `.get()` with a default value.

```
class SampleViewSet(ParentListAPIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        _email = self.request.data.get('email', "default@email.com")
```

Comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you" -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers